# Mulesoft Environments

Tags: mulesoft

Is there a prescribed best practice for being able to run multiple environments in a single VPC? I'm asking for Non-Prod - I want to setup a Dev and a QA environment, would I just need to setup separate subnets for these individual environments?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requirements and resources available. Ideally you should have a different VPC for QA and Dev environments. If your security requirements are not that strict you could use the same VPC for both.

I'm not quite sure if I understand the separate subnets part. Each VPC has its own subnet. Environments don't have subnets.

Comment: thanks, you should be able to add multiple subnets within one VPC and assign a CIDR block to it right?

Comment: Maybe you are confusing a VPC with a VPN? A VPC is a network, with a single CIDR. A VPN connects two networks with encrypted tunnels, one being the VPC, the other an external network.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with same VPC for all Non-PROD environments. And for the PROD (or Similar to PROD) environments will go with another VPC. This way you can easily make more strict network rules around the PROD VPC. Aled's point is very valid if you are using sensitive data for SIT testing.

Also each VPC has its own VPN and it CIDR block.

You can easily create difference environments and access restrictions to allow and restrict your testers/developers.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I ended up doing. BTW - any recommendations around mulesoft worker sizes?

Comment: Depends on the memory usage of the application and how many parallel calls happening. vCore is tightly coupled with memory in Mule (as of now). You can try allocating 0.1vcore and increasing it later. We control it from maven.